# JS for Kids Hangman game

Tags: javascript

I don't know what the `[i]` in `answerArray[i]` does/means. If someone could explain what it does it would mean a lot. This code came from the book "JavaScript for kids" and I'm trying to get started with just any kind of coding

```
var words = [
"money",
"pillow",
"maracas"
];

var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];

var answerArray = [];
```

Here

```
for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
*answerArray[i] = "_";* 
}

var remainingLetters = word.length;

while (remainingLetters > 0) {
alert(answerArray.join(" "));
var guess = prompt("Guess a letter, or click cancel to stop playing.");
if (guess === null) {
break;
} else if (guess.length !== 1) {
alert("Please enter a single letter.");
} else {
```

And here

```
*for (var j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
if (word[j] === guess) {
 answerArray[j] = guess;*
 remainingLetters--;
}
}
}
}

alert(answerArray.join(" "));
alert("Good job! The answer was " + word);
```

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: It's referencing an array item by index. For example, if you have an array like `var fruits = ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']` and you do `var myFruit = fruits[1]` it will be set to "Bananas". (Arrays are 0-index, so 0 is the first item, and so on). By doing a loop, you're increasing `i` each time - so `array[i]` is looping through every item in the array one-by-one. Consider doing some basic research on arrays - they're fundamental programming knowledge across just about every single programming language, therefore there's plenty of documentation out there (like the resource @j08691 posted).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example

https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_loop_for_ex

The letters `i` or `j` or litterally anything put in that slot when you write `for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)` represents the current `itteration`. This is thing called a `for loop` and you should definitely get to know it if you are just getting started with javascript.

The letter, in short, represents the current itteration of the loop.

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)  { }
```

What this loop is saying is first `i = 0`. the variable "i" is 0. Then it says `i < 5`. This part is the "test". If the test passes, the loop with run again. Then it says `i++`. This is something that happens **after** the loop has been run. In this example it increases `i` with 1.

What happens inside `{ }` will occure 5 times, and the letter `i` will increase in value, representing the "current loop".

In the demo i linked, you see that the sentence "The number is x" appears in increasing order, starting with 0.

The loop essentially means "While i is less than 5, do this" and the `i` increases in value each loop and the test inside `()` is rerun.

In arrays, each slot is represented by a number. `MyArray[1]` refers to the second item in the array.
If you have an array like this `var myArray = ["fi", "fa", "fo"]`  then you can write `console.log[2]` to print the third item.

Lets combine this knowledge like this!

```
var myArray = ["fi", "fa", "fo"];

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   alert(myArray[i]);
}
```

The for-loop is run 3 times, and each time it is run, `i` has a bigger value. This lets us refer to every item in the array. A better loop to write would be `for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++`. This makes us compare `i` to the size of your array, so the array can be any size it wants to be

Answer (score 0):

1 > the answer array initially empty array=[];

2 >  then   `words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)]` this will return a 
   random string from words array .

3 > then the for loop is just counting the number of characters present in the 
    selected word and that same time number of `_` is inserted in answers Array

4 > then this will just joining all the underscores and make a single `string` (with in the spaces).

eg -> word "**pillow**" is selected

then answers Array= `['_','_','_','_','_','_']`

then answerArray= `"_ _ _ _ _ _"` ( Join with spaces).

Thanks.